# get some information for a selected dropdownlist item which is stored in the database

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, client-side

I'm on a asp.net mvc3 project using razor.

What is the easiest way to get some information for a selected dropdownlist item which is stored in the database? Should be client side - mouse over a image icon right behind the dropdownlist...

I tried this, but it's not complete, because I don't want to hardcode 'Acronis' in the javascript code.

view:

<

```
script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var backup = document.getElementById("backupList")
        $('#backupList').change(function () {

            if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].text == 'Acronis') {
                $("#imageQm").show();
                $("#imageQm").attr('title', '@(Html.GetBackupDescription("Acronis"))');             }

        }).trigger('change');
    });
</script>
 @Html.DropDownList("backupList")

 <img id="imageQm" src="Images/question-icon.png" alt="?"  />
```

database:

```
Backup

ID Name      Description

1  Acronis   ...
```

```
public static class HtmlHelpers {

  public static string GetBackupDescription(this HtmlHelper helper, string s) {

    ChecklisteEntities db = new Entities();

    IQueryable<server_backup> query = from p in db.server_backup

                                      where p.name == s

                                      select p;

    List<server_backup> liste = query.ToList();

    return liste[0].description;

}
```

For any questions please reply :)

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you'll need to add a few pieces to make this work properly.  What you have included in your razor view will be evaluated at the time the view is constructed, **NOT** when the item is selected in the drop down.

You will either need to supply the additional description as part of your model that gets sent to the view initially, or create a service to call that will return the data you expect.

Just remember that anything you must preface with '@' within your view is only evaluated when the view is constructed on the server, once this is done, it's simple html that is delivered to the browser.

My suggestion would be to send down both pieces of data with the initial view and have your javascript simply pull that value out of the dom to make visible.